# ESB MULE passing the parameters to the java method

Tags: mule, invoke, payload, inbound

I use MULE version 3.3.0 CE, I want to get some value from header in inbound and then pass it to a java method, in java method making some changes on passed value, finally again I pass it from java method to the outbound????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of tying your Java beans to the Mule API (with `Callable`), you can do this using MEL only, for example with:

```
<invoke object-ref="yourBean"
        method="yourMethod"
        methodArguments="#[message.inboundProperties['inboundPropertyName']]" />

<set-property propertyName="outboundPropertyName"
              value="#[payload]" />
```

This has the caveat that the message payload is affected by the `invoke` element. If this is a problem then you can go with:

```
<expression-component>
    propVal = app.registry.yourBean.yourMethod(message.inboundProperties['inboundPropertyName']);
    message.outboundProperties['outboundPropertyName'] = propVal;
</expression-component>
```

Comment: In the second form, are flowVars/InvocationProperties considered inbound, outbound, or something else?

Comment: Something else: they are flow variables, i.e. accessible in the `flowVars` map and, unless you deactivated this feature, as global variables of the MEL script.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make your Java component implement org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable
2. In its onCall you can get the message as follows:

   MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();
3. Now you can obtain the inbound properties:

   Object someProp = message.getInboundProperty("some_prop_name");
4. After operating over it, you place it back as an outbound property:

   message.setOutboundProperty("some_prop_name", someProp);

Comment: thanks for your reply. :)  Can you more explain about it? first I set a variable in .mflow file then in java class callable get it ??