# Mule invoke message processor

Tags: spring, mule

I came across "invoke" element ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223807/esb-mule-passing-the-parameters-to-the-java-method)) that can be used to invoke java methods from inside the flow. It seemed a perfect solutions for me, since I don't want to use Callable and entry points resolvers and I want to pass extra parameter to the method.

```
<invoke object-ref="yourBean"
        method="yourMethod"
        methodArguments="#[message.inboundProperties['inboundPropertyName']]" />

<set-property propertyName="outboundPropertyName"
              value="#[payload]" />
```

I did something like the code above. My question is: how should I create "yourBean"?
I tried to create:

```
<spring:bean name="yourBean" class="class"/>
```

but got:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'yourBean' is defined
```

I also have other beans defined in my  tag, but others seemed to work. Does anyone have similar issue?

EDIT:
When I deleted other beans definitions besides "yourBean" everything started to work, but when I add more beans definitions I got following error when I tried to use "yourBean":

```
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.processor.InvokerMessageProcessor:280 (null)
2. null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:35 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.ht
ml)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.mule.processor.InvokerMessageProcessor.transformArgument(InvokerMessageProcessor.java:280)
        at org.mule.processor.InvokerMessageProcessor.evaluateArguments(InvokerMessageProcessor.java:200)
        at org.mule.processor.InvokerMessageProcessor.process(InvokerMessageProcessor.java:164)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Which for me seems like the "yourBean" is not instantiated. But why?

My bean definitions:

```
<bean id="yourBean" class="com.example.BpmService"/>

    <bean id="StatusUpdateContext" class="javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext" factory-method="newInstance">
        <constructor-arg>
            <array>
                <value type="java.lang.Class">
                    com.example.OrderStatusUpdate
                </value>
            </array>
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, id/name both some to work for Mule invoke. I have had no problems using invoke with multiple bean definitions. This sounds more like an issue with your beans, which you are not sharing, and/or Spring than Mule invoke.

Comment: I search for the difference between id and name and it doesn't seem to be a problem here. I updated my question with more information.